# c++ criticalsection for getter

Tags: c++, multithreading, critical-section

I have a simple class with one private member that is accessible via get() and set() in a multithreaded environment (multi readers/multi writers). how do I lock a Get() as it only has a return statement?

```
class MyValue
{
  private:
    System::CriticalSection lock;
    int val { 0 };

  public:
    int SetValue(int arg)
    {
        lock.Enter();
        val = arg;
        lock.Leave();
    }

    int GetValue()
    {
        lock.Enter();
        return val;
        //Where should I do lock.Leave()?
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use an atomic variable if it is called very often. If C++ is not available then there are system functions like the Interlock family on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't lock anything. In your example, it is enough if you make your member an `std::atomic` integer.

You do not need anything else here. As a matter of fact, due to Intel architecture (strong memory ordering model), this `std::atomic` is not even likely to cause any performance issues.

Comment: really? wow. 'll look it up. does the context of this object matters? because it lives as a "value" on a local implementation of unordered map. so it will work even if there are multiple readers and multiple writer threads accessing it at a time?

Comment: @bsobaid, doesn't matter where the object lives. You are making the member atomic, saying, that every time you read it, it should be properly read (so that you see the latest update), and when you write, writes have to be committed. It also forbids reordering. So you are cool ;)

Comment: iam using VS2013. do I need to include anything? intellisense not showing atomic after std::.  It shows me std::_Atomic_integral_t but I believe this is something different.

Comment: the return and arg type of GetVal() and SetVal() should also change to std::atomic_int or I think that can remain as int?

Comment: No, in fact, you won't be able to make them atomic. They are to remain int.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a multithreading expert, but I think following should work.

```
int GetValue()
{
    lock.Enter();
    int ret = val;
    lock.Leave();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: but what if thread A is executing "return ret" and thread b is executing int ret = val ??

Comment: @bsobaid If I understand multithreading correctly, each thread will have it's own copy of all local variables (`int ret` int this case) when he executes the function. So, it will not be a problem.

Comment: @bsobaid then you'll have a dirty read (google it: A dirty read (aka uncommitted dependency) occurs when a transaction is allowed to read data from a row that has been modified by another running transaction and not yet committed.)

Comment: actually I amok with dirty read. i-e thread A reads val as10 and when its on return ret, thread B comes and set val =20. in this case thread A has stale value. I am ok with that.

Comment: Depending on the architecture of your system, you may get away with using a shared int value without a lock, you won't get a garbage value.

Comment: @bsobaid @José @hauron But every thread has it's own stack. Every thread will have it's own copy of `int ret;`, so "dirty read" will be impossible. Or do I understand something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

This is a demonstration of the synchronization object from hauron's answer -- I wanted to show that object construction and destruction overhead simply does not exist with an optomized build.

In the code below, CCsGrabber is an RAII-like class which enters a critical section (wrapped by a CCritical object) when constructed, then leaves it when destroyed:

```
class CCsGrabber {
    class CCritical& m_Cs;
    CCsGrabber();
public:
    CCsGrabber(CCritical& cs);
    ~CCsGrabber();
};

class CCritical {
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
public:
    CCritical()       { 
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs); 
    }
    ~CCritical()      { DeleteCriticalSection(&cs); }
    void Enter()      { EnterCriticalSection(&cs); }
    void Leave()      { LeaveCriticalSection(&cs); }
    void Lock()       { Enter(); }
    void Unlock()     { Leave(); }
};

inline CCsGrabber::CCsGrabber(CCritical& cs)  : m_Cs(cs)   { m_Cs.Enter(); }
inline CCsGrabber::CCsGrabber(CCritical *pcs) : m_Cs(*pcs) { m_Cs.Enter(); }
inline CCsGrabber::~CCsGrabber()                           { m_Cs.Leave(); }
```

Now, a global CCritical object is created (cs), which is used in `SerialFunc()`, along with a local CCsGrabber instance (csg) to take care of locking and unlocking:

```
CCritical cs;
DWORD last_tick = 0;

void SerialFunc() {
    CCsGrabber csg(cs);
    last_tick = GetTickCount();
}

int main() {
    SerialFunc();
    std::cout << last_tick << std::endl;
}
```

And below is the dissasembly of main() from an optimized 32-bit build. (I apologize for pasting in the whole thing -- I wanted to show that I wasn't hiding anything:

```
int main() {
00401C80  push        ebp  
00401C81  mov         ebp,esp  
00401C83  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
00401C86  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
00401C88  push        41B038h  
00401C8D  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
00401C93  push        eax  
00401C94  mov         dword ptr fs:[0],esp  
00401C9B  sub         esp,0Ch  
00401C9E  push        esi  
00401C9F  push        edi  
    SerialFunc();
00401CA0  push        427B78h                          ; pointer to CS object
00401CA5  call        dword ptr ds:[41C00Ch]           ; _RtlEnterCriticalSection@4:
00401CAB  call        dword ptr ds:[41C000h]           ; _GetTickCountStub@0:
00401CB1  push        427B78h                          ; pointer to CS object
00401CB6  mov         dword ptr ds:[00427B74h],eax     ; return value => last_tick
00401CBB  call        dword ptr ds:[41C008h]           ; _RtlLeaveCriticalSection@4: 
    std::cout << last_tick << std::endl;
00401CC1  push        ecx  
00401CC2  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0401D90h)  
00401CC7  mov         esi,eax  
00401CC9  lea         eax,[esp+0Ch]  
00401CCD  push        eax  
00401CCE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi]  
00401CD0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
00401CD3  add         ecx,esi  
00401CD5  call        std::ios_base::getloc (0401BD0h)  
00401CDA  push        eax  
00401CDB  mov         dword ptr [esp+20h],0  
00401CE3  call        std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> > (0403E40h)  
00401CE8  mov         dword ptr [esp+20h],0FFFFFFFFh  
00401CF0  add         esp,4  
00401CF3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+0Ch]  
00401CF7  mov         edi,eax  
00401CF9  test        ecx,ecx  
00401CFB  je          main+8Eh (0401D0Eh)  
00401CFD  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx]  
00401CFF  call        dword ptr [edx+8]  
00401D02  test        eax,eax  
00401D04  je          main+8Eh (0401D0Eh)  
00401D06  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
00401D08  mov         ecx,eax  
00401D0A  push        1  
00401D0C  call        dword ptr [edx]  
00401D0E  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi]  
00401D10  mov         ecx,edi  
00401D12  push        0Ah  
00401D14  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+20h]  
00401D17  call        eax  
00401D19  movzx       eax,al  
00401D1C  mov         ecx,esi  
00401D1E  push        eax  
00401D1F  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::put (0404220h)  
00401D24  mov         ecx,esi  
00401D26  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::flush (0402EB0h)  
}
00401D2B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+14h]  
00401D2F  xor         eax,eax  
00401D31  pop         edi  
00401D32  mov         dword ptr fs:[0],ecx  
00401D39  pop         esi  
00401D3A  mov         esp,ebp  
00401D3C  pop         ebp  
00401D3D  ret
```

So we can see that SerialFunc() was inlined directly into main, after prologue at the beginning and before the cout code -- and nowhere to be found is any superflouous object creation, memory allocation or anything -- it just looks like the minimum amount of assembly code required to enter the critical section, get the tick count in a variable, and then leave the critical section.

Then I changed `SerialFunc()` to:

```
void SerialFunc() {
    cs.Enter();
    last_tick = GetTickCount();
    cs.Leave();
}
```

With explicitly-placed `cs.Enter()` and `cs.Leave()`, just to compare with the RAII version.  The generated code turned out to be identical:

```
    int main() {
00401C80  push        ebp  
00401C81  mov         ebp,esp  
00401C83  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
00401C86  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
00401C88  push        41B038h  
00401C8D  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
00401C93  push        eax  
00401C94  mov         dword ptr fs:[0],esp  
00401C9B  sub         esp,0Ch  
00401C9E  push        esi  
00401C9F  push        edi  
        SerialFunc();
00401CA0  push        427B78h  
00401CA5  call        dword ptr ds:[41C00Ch]  
00401CAB  call        dword ptr ds:[41C000h]  
00401CB1  push        427B78h  
00401CB6  mov         dword ptr ds:[00427B74h],eax  
00401CBB  call        dword ptr ds:[41C008h]  
        std::cout << last_tick << std::endl;
00401CC1  push        ecx  
00401CC2  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0401D90h)  
                         ...
```

In my opinion, SergeyA's answer is best for the given situation -- a critical section for synchronizing reads and writes from/to 32-bit variables is excessive. However, if something comes up which calls for a critical section or mutex, using an RAII-like object to simplify your code is probably not going to incur significant (or even any) object creation overhead.

(I used Visual C++ 2013 to compile the code above)

Comment: where is CRITSEC_OBJECT  defined?

Comment: Sorry about that -- CRITSEC_OBJECT was just a typedef of CRITICAL_SECTION that I missed when I pasted the code here.  I made an edit, replacing it with CRITICAL_SECTION.

Comment: np. What is the difference between your critical section and System::CriticalSection that has member functions Enter() and Leave() as opposed to EnterCriticalSection(), LeaveCriticalSection(). I believe yours in C-style and System::CriticalSection is C++?

Comment: @bsobaid CCritical is a C++ class which manages the lifetime of a Win32 Critical Section and provides member functions corresponding to API calls which act on the owned Critical Section object.  It provides a C++ wrapper for the Win32 API's C-like interface.  I'm not familar with a class named System::CriticalSection, but it sounds like a similar C++ wrapper for an underlying Win32 Critical Section object and its functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a class wrapper locking in ctor, and unlocking in dtor. See standard implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock

This way you don't need to remember about unlocking in case of complex code or exceptions thrown within your code, altering the normal execution.

Comment: in my case this is called thousands of times in a seconds by 100 threads. construction and destruction of so many objects will be a overhead? application is super performance sensitive.

Comment: @bsobaid if so, then I'm afraid it will be an overhead (the above locking/unlocking mechanism as well). What you need, is a shared-unique mutex combination. A writer (setter) should try to lock the mutex exclusively. This will only succeed if no reader (getter) is holding the lock. The reader does not need exclusive access, and can hold a shared lock voer the mutex.

Comment: @bsobaid consider this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock (for an implementation see boost's upgrade lock: a lock over a mutex than can "upgrade" to unique access)

Comment: I am using VS2013. would'nt mutex be expensive as it goes into kernel mode whereas criticalsection remains in usermode until contested?

Comment: @bsobaid possibly, it's hard to say. And whenever it's hard to say: profile, profile, profile. Remember if you had thousands of reads and only few writes, the mutexes would be way cheaper (as using CriticalSection every read requires exclusive access, afaik).

Comment: in my case the read and write are more or less same frequency, actually there can be slightly more writes than read. I found some stackoverflow links and mutex was taking much longer than crisec

Comment: @bsobaid, yes, on Windows critical sections are much faster than mutexes. However, you need neither.

Comment: You should find that `std::mutex` is impleneted on Windows by a WinAPI CRITICALSECTION (not a WinAPI Mutex)

Comment: @M.M so f std::mutex uses criticalsection and (and therefore remains in user mode??) how can such mutex can work intra-process? as this is the fundamental characterstic of a mutex.

Comment: @bsobaid In standard C++ there is no inter-process, only inter-thread.  To do inter-process synchronization you have to use operating system facilities.